# Wix Installer "WixUIDialogBmp" not shown on Win 7

Tags: wix

I have a Wix installer with this line:

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="Images\d.bmp" />
```

When running the MSI on Win 10 the image appears OK, on Win 7 the image is gone. Couldn't find an answer on Google.

The dimensions are 493X312.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was strange - changed to format to jpg and all is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the bitmap's size solved this problem for me. I did this by reducing the image's bit depth from 24- to 8-bits.